# When using an AutoCompleteTextView, can I run code between user clicking and populating the textbox with the answer?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to recreate functionality, when one of the suggestions in an AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView is clicked, I want to check if a variable is set to a specific value, if so, ignore that click and do not populate the textbox, otherwise the click is fine and the textbox is filled ok.

Apologies it's a new widget for me so I'm still learning the methods at the moment and it doesn't seem obvious.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by binding the AutoCompleteTextView `setOnItemClickListenerlistner`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);



        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // Check here if selected text is valid
                // otherwise remove the text from textview
            }
        });

    }

   private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
   };
}
```